# Retornar IQueryable no método

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Estou utilizando IdentityFramework no meu projeto e preciso criar um método que retorne um IQueryable
Segue abaixo estrutura da classe:

```
namespace MeuProjeto.Controllers
    public class UsuariosController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

        public UsuariosController(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
                                  UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
                                  RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
                                  IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
        }

        public IQueryable<Usuario> ObterUsuarios1()
        {
            return _userManager.Users
                    .Select(u => new Usuario() { Id = u.Id, Name = u.UserName, Email = u.Email, Claims = ???? })
                    .OrderBy(u => u.Name);
        }

        public async Task<IQueryable<Usuario>> ObterUsuarios2()
        {
            var lista = new List<Usuario>();
            var usuarios = _userManager.Users.ToList();
            foreach (var usuario in usuarios)
            {
                var claims = (await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(usuario)).Select(c => new UsuarioClaim { Type = c.Type, Value = c.Value });
                var novoUsuario = new Usuario() { Id = usuario.Id, Name = u.UserName, Email = usuario.Email, Claims = claims };
                lista.Add(novoUsuario);
            }

            return lista.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

Estrutura de Usuario e UsuarioClaim:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UsuarioClaim> Claims { get; set; }
}

public class UsuarioClaim
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Preciso fazer com que um dos métodos funcionem.

- No Método **ObterUsuarios1** eu não consegui adicionar as Claims, mas
  está retornando IQueryable corretamente.
- No método **ObterUsuarios2** eu consegui adicionar as Claims, mas
  está dando um erro quando tento utilizar o retorno.

Mensagem de erro utilizando o retorno de ObterUsuarios2 (AsQueryable):

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IAsyncQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.
```

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou o código abaixo?

```
 public IQueryable<Usuario> ObterUsuarios()
        {
            return _userManager.Users
                    .Include(u => u.UsuarioClaim)
                    .OrderBy(u => u.Name);
        }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, Shai Pinto!
Mas pra mim está dando erro no include. Entendo que _userManager.Users seria de IdentityUser onde não tem o UsuarioClaim.

Comment: Será que o erro não é referente ao retorno do método ser uma Task. Tente: 

return Task.FromResult<IQueryable<Usuario>>(lista.AsQueryable())